# Построить треугольник из символов на паскале

Tags: pascal, циклы, символы

**Задание:** 
пользователь вводит непарное число `n >= 5`, а программа строит "ёлку" из треугольников типа: `n = 7`; основа треугольника 7 символов, выше 5 символов еще выше 3 символа а вверху 1. Символ может быть любым(например *).

Comment: Вы попытайтесь написать хоть что-то, а мы подскажем как быть. Никто не хочет за Вас решать ваши учебные задания. Возможно кому то из нас потом еще с Вами придется работать ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ух, "непарное" - дохнуло стариной :) Имеется в виду нечётное. Возможна куча реализаций. Например, так (без проверок ввода на чётность, правильность и т.п. Наверняка не самая оптимальная):

```
var
  i,k,j,l,m:integer;
  s,s1:string;
begin
  readln(k);
  j:= k div 2;
  m:=1;
  for i:=1 to j+1 do
    begin
       s:=''; s1:='';
       for l:=1 to j do s:=s+ ' ';
       for l:=1 to m do s1:=s1+'*';
       writeln(s,s1,s);
       inc(m,2); dec(j,1);
    end;
end;
```

Ну, а вообще здесь не приветствуются вопросы в стиле "дяденьки, помогите мне решить контрольную", поэтому комментировать свой код я не буду. Если разберётесь, значит, половину задачи сделали сами :)

Comment: спасибо, и извините если вас напряг школьный вопрос
p.s. и это олимпиадная задача :)

Comment: Какой класс? Слабенько как-то... у меня сын в 8м на питоне такие вещи, как обычные задачки проходит.